# How to decode bencoded torrent data

Tags: python, python-2.7, decode, bittorrent, bencoding

I'm trying to extract size and name from a torrent file with decoding the content of a torrent file with bencode.

I did `pip install bencode` then I tested with one of the line of a torrent file as you can see there.

```
import bencode

blabla = 'd8:announce70:http://tracker.t411.io:56969/c5faa6720249d33ff6ba2af48640af89/announce7:comment29:https://www.t411.io/t/524280210:created by19:https://www.t411.io13:creation datei1431685353e4:infod6:lengthi14634059e4:name22:Charlie-Hebdo-1178.pdf12:piece lengthi262144e6:pieces1120:'
myprint = bencode.decode_string(blabla,1)
print myprint
```

This is the file that pip install put in the python lib:

```
from BTL import BTFailure


def decode_int(x, f):
    f += 1
    newf = x.index('e', f)
    n = int(x[f:newf])
    if x[f] == '-':
        if x[f + 1] == '0':
            raise ValueError
    elif x[f] == '0' and newf != f+1:
        raise ValueError
    return (n, newf+1)

def decode_string(x, f):
    colon = x.index(':', f)
    n = int(x[f:colon])
    if x[f] == '0' and colon != f+1:
        raise ValueError
    colon += 1
    return (x[colon:colon+n], colon+n)

def decode_list(x, f):
    r, f = [], f+1
    while x[f] != 'e':
        v, f = decode_func[x[f]](x, f)
        r.append(v)
    return (r, f + 1)

def decode_dict(x, f):
    r, f = {}, f+1
    while x[f] != 'e':
        k, f = decode_string(x, f)
        r[k], f = decode_func[x[f]](x, f)
    return (r, f + 1)

decode_func = {}
decode_func['l'] = decode_list
decode_func['d'] = decode_dict
decode_func['i'] = decode_int
decode_func['0'] = decode_string
decode_func['1'] = decode_string
decode_func['2'] = decode_string
decode_func['3'] = decode_string
decode_func['4'] = decode_string
decode_func['5'] = decode_string
decode_func['6'] = decode_string
decode_func['7'] = decode_string
decode_func['8'] = decode_string
decode_func['9'] = decode_string

def bdecode(x):
    try:
        r, l = decode_func[x[0]](x, 0)
    except (IndexError, KeyError, ValueError):
        raise BTFailure("not a valid bencoded string")
    if l != len(x):
        raise BTFailure("invalid bencoded value (data after valid prefix)")
    return r

from types import StringType, IntType, LongType, DictType, ListType, TupleType


class Bencached(object):

    __slots__ = ['bencoded']

    def __init__(self, s):
        self.bencoded = s

def encode_bencached(x,r):
    r.append(x.bencoded)

def encode_int(x, r):
    r.extend(('i', str(x), 'e'))

def encode_bool(x, r):
    if x:
        encode_int(1, r)
    else:
        encode_int(0, r)

def encode_string(x, r):
    r.extend((str(len(x)), ':', x))

def encode_list(x, r):
    r.append('l')
    for i in x:
        encode_func[type(i)](i, r)
    r.append('e')

def encode_dict(x,r):
    r.append('d')
    ilist = x.items()
    ilist.sort()
    for k, v in ilist:
        r.extend((str(len(k)), ':', k))
        encode_func[type(v)](v, r)
    r.append('e')

encode_func = {}
encode_func[Bencached] = encode_bencached
encode_func[IntType] = encode_int
encode_func[LongType] = encode_int
encode_func[StringType] = encode_string
encode_func[ListType] = encode_list
encode_func[TupleType] = encode_list
encode_func[DictType] = encode_dict

try:
    from types import BooleanType
    encode_func[BooleanType] = encode_bool
except ImportError:
    pass

def bencode(x):
    r = []
    encode_func[type(x)](x, r)
    return ''.join(r)
```

The fact is that I don't really understand how can I decode my line with this bencode.

I already tried the def `bdecode` but this is the output:

```
root@debian:/home/florian/Téléchargements# python decript.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "decript.py", line 4, in <module>
    myprint = bencode.bdecode(blabla)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bencode/__init__.py", line 68, in bdecode
    raise BTFailure("not a valid bencoded string")
bencode.BTL.BTFailure: not a valid bencoded string
```

So I tried with the def `decode_string` but with `decode_string(blabla, 1)` it decode only the first word:

```
root@debian:/home/florian/Téléchargements# python decript.py 
('announce', 11)
```

and the number like 2, 3, 4 don't work and display error like:

```
root@debian:/home/florian/Téléchargements# python decript.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "decript.py", line 4, in <module>
    myprint = bencode.decode_string(blabla,10)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bencode/__init__.py", line 29, in decode_string
    n = int(x[f:colon])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'e70'
```

I want to decode all the line and I don't understand how can I do it with this bencode for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an incomplete Bencoded string.

The first part tells you there is a dictionary:

```
d...
```

which is supposed to be parsed until there is an `e` character. There is no such character in your input string.

A manual parse shows you have the keys `announce`, `comment`, `created by`, `creation date`, and `info`, where the latter is a nested dictionary with `length`, `name`, `piece-length` and `pieces`. Then your string *stops*; there is no value for `pieces`, and no `e` to mark the end of either the outer dictionary or the nested `info` dictionary. All we have is the type and length indicator: `1120`.

You could try and use the decoding functions directly, but then take into account that they return the value *and the offset*:

```
>>> bencode.decode_string(blabla, 1)
('announce', 11)
```

11 is the offset for the next value:

```
>>> bencode.decode_string(blabla, 11)
('http://tracker.t411.io:56969/c5faa6720249d33ff6ba2af48640af89/announce', 84)
```

and 84 is again the next:

```
>>> bencode.decode_string(blabla, 84)
('comment', 93)
```

If you take into account that the string is incomplete and that not all encoded objects are strings, you can still decode what little is there.

The offset also tells you what function to use for decoding:

```
>>> blabla[1]
'8'
>>> bencode.decode_func[blabla[1]]
<function decode_string at 0x1004632a8>
```

The number here spells out how many characters to expect. So skipping the failing `d` dictionary mapping you get:

```
>>> offset = 1
>>> while True:
...     value, offset = bencode.decode_func[blabla[offset]](blabla, offset)
...     print value
... 
announce
http://tracker.t411.io:56969/c5faa6720249d33ff6ba2af48640af89/announce
comment
https://www.t411.io/t/5242802
created by
https://www.t411.io
creation date
1431685353
info
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/Users/mj/Development/venvs/stackoverflow-2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bencode/__init__.py", line 44, in decode_dict
    while x[f] != 'e':
IndexError: string index out of range
```

which fails because you hit the nested dictionary without `e`. You could extract those keys too, by adding one to the last offset:

```
>>> offset
194
>>> blabla[offset]
'd'
>>> offset += 1
>>> while True:
...     value, offset = bencode.decode_func[blabla[offset]](blabla, offset)
...     print value
... 
length
14634059
name
Charlie-Hebdo-1178.pdf
piece length
262144
pieces

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Or you could just read the data as *binary* data and not truncate it:

```
with open(torrentfilename, 'rb') as torrentfile:
    torrent = bencode.bdecode(torrentfile.read())
# now you have a dictionary.
```

Comment: "The first part tells you there is a dictionary with 8 elements". That's incorrect.

Comment: @the8472: oops, indeed. That's just the encoded string length.

Comment: I think i finally understand thank you very much for your very nice answer.
In fast i just want to extract the name and the size for each `.torrent`  file and then the hash after but the offset is never the same so i have to detect the "name" and "lenght" inside my script i guess.
And why the script stop with a `e` ? Because if want to read all the informations...
(Sorry for my python level)
@MartijnPieters

Comment: @Bouh10: it is much easier to just read the file properly. The `bencode` *format* uses `d` and `e` to mark the start and end of a dictionary (it uses `e` to mark the end of integers and lists as well); the code parses the file until the next offset points to an `e` in the character sequence.

Comment: @Bouh10: a properly encoded `torrent` file will be parsed in one; each dictionary, list or integer in there will have an `e` marking the end of that specific encoded object. So you can have `d...d..e...e` and that encodes a dictionary containing another dictionary.

Comment: Oh okay, there is not much informations about bencode on internet...
Do you have an idea of the best way to extract the size, the name and the hash without any problem ?

Comment: @Bouh10: I already answered that. Read the file, pass the contents to `bdecode()` and `torrent` is the resulting dictionary. `torrent['info']['name']` gives you the name, `torrent['info']['length']` the size of the torrent, etc.

Comment: @Bouh10: also see [this description of the contents](https://wiki.theory.org/BitTorrentSpecification#Metainfo_File_Structure).

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Indeed sorry you edited it so much time ^^
Thanks alot for your help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78709/discussion-between-bouh10-and-martijn-pieters).

Answer (score 4):

The string you're trying to decode seems to be truncated. it ends in `pieces1120:`, indicating that at least 1120 bytes should follow.

BEncoding is a binary format. It's only partially human-readable and not meant to be embedded in charset-sensitive things such as source code files. I suggest you read it straight from a file.

Comment: You mean that i should not take a line from the file in gedit but read it straight with a command in my script right ?

Comment: you shouldn't decode "a line", you should decode the whole file at once. bencoding is not line-based. and yes, use file-IO in your script.